# Check for substring efficiently for large data sets

Tags: java, cassandra, substring, cassandra-3.0

**I have:**

- a database table with 400 000 000 rows (Cassandra 3)
- a list of circa 10 000 keywords
- both data sets are expected to grow in time

**I need to:**

- check if a specified column contains a keyword
- sum how many rows contained the keyword in the column

Which approach should I choose?

**Approach 1 (Secondary index):**

- Create secondary [SASI index on the table](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html)
- Find matches for given keyword "on fly" anytime
- However, I am afraid of

  - *cappacity problem* - secondary indices can consume extra space and for such large table it could be too much
  - *performance* - I am not sure if finding of keyword among hundreds milions of rows can be achieved in a reasonable time

**Approach 2 (Java job - brute force):**

- Java job that continuously iterates over data
- Matches are saved into cache
- Cache is updated during the next iteration

  ```
  // Paginate throuh data...
  String page = null;
  do {
    PagingState state = page == null ? null : PagingState.fromString(page);
    PagedResult<DataRow> res = getDataPaged(query, status, PAGE_SIZE, state);

    // Iterate through the current page ...
    for (DataRow row : res.getResult()) {

      // Skip empty titles
      if (row.getTitle().length() == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      // Find match in title
      for (String k : keywords) {
        if (k.length() > row.getTitle().length()) {
          continue;
        }
        if (row.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(k.toLowerCase()) {
          // TODO: SAVE match
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    status = res.getResult();
    page = res.getPage();

    // TODO: Wait here to reduce DB load

  } while (page != null);
  ```
- Problems

  - It could be very slow to iterate through whole table. If I waited for one second per every 1000 rows, then this cycle would finish in 4.6 days
  - This would require extra space for cache; moreover, frequent deletions from cache would produce tombstones in Cassandra

Comment: What about running option 2 once and create a cache (can be an external resource) and for future updates use a filter mechanism that update cache after storing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way will be to use a search engine like SolR our ElasticSearch. Full text search is their speciality. You could easily dump your data from cassandra to Elasticsearch and implement your java job on top of ElasticSearch.

**EDIT:**

With Cassandra you can request your result query as a JSON and Elasticsearch 'speak' only in JSON so you will be able to transfer your data very easily.

[Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch?elektra=home&storm=banner)

[SolR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: Thank you, could you be more specific on "easily dump your data from cassandra to Elasticsearch"?